# Не появляется package json в gulp

Tags: json, gulp

```
C:\Users\Dev>cd /d e:/webdev/prj

e:\WEBDEV\prj>npm i gulp --save-dev
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs v3.0.0 and before will fail on node releases >= v7.0. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible. Use 'npm ls graceful-fs' to find it in the tree.
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'e:\WEBDEV\prj\package.json'
e:\WEBDEV\prj
`-- gulp@3.9.1

npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'e:\WEBDEV\prj\package.json'
npm WARN prj No description
npm WARN prj No repository field.
npm WARN prj No README data
npm WARN prj No license field.
```

Выдает вот это. Что делать?

Comment: Перед тем как загружать пакеты нужно создать package.json, в котором будут описаны все зависимости поекта. Инициализировать его можно командой npm init. Инфа тут: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно запустить команду npm init, пройти весь процесс и package.json сохраниться, а дальше уже добавлять плагины.